# Custom code to drive pages with the same name as custom post types in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

If I create pages, I can create custom template php files to drive them. e.g., the page "Villages" I can drive with "page-villages.php instead of its default "page.php"

However. If I have a custom post type named "town" and I try to create a page with the name "Towns", I can't seem to be able to have a php file named "page-towns.php" to drive it, it always defaults "index.php"

It may have to do with the registering?

```
  register_post_type('town', array(  /* by default, the post type name is the SLUG for that post type*/
    'public' => true, /* makes post type visible to admins, editors, etc*/
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields'),
    'has_archive' => true, /* make post type have a archive URL */
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'towns'), /*plural name for the SLUG instead of default singular name */
    'labels' => array(
      'name' => 'Towns',
      'add_new_item' => 'Add New Town',
      'edit_item' => 'Edit Town',
      'all_items' => 'All Towns',
      'singular_name' => 'Town'
    ),
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-admin-multisite'
  ));
```

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [**single-{post}.php** template file](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/post-template-files/#single-php).

If the file **single.php** exists, Wordpress will use that when viewing a single post. Custom post types will use that file too. If you want to override it, use **single-{your-post-name}.php**

In your case you'd use ***single-towns.php***

-

Also, I believe you should name custom post types with a singular name, so perhaps update to using *town* as your post name, then you'd use *single-town.php* as your template file.

Comment: that is correct, my bad, the custom post type is "town", but the page I am creating is "towns" and when I try to go to the slug "\towns\",  the default php file being used is "index.php" instead of "page.php" or "page-town.php".  I will correct my mistakes above

Comment: @JakeSays you have a couple options;
1) Create a [Rewrite on your post type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#rewrite)
2) Create a [Custom Archive Template](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Type_Templates)
3) Create your page called Towns and edit the page template to include a custom post loop for your post "Town".